# Parsing a list and string into DataFrame header

Tags: python, pandas

My code:

```
coins = ['dashcoin','litecoin','dogecoin','nxt']
pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp',coins])
```

I need a header with 5 different values, but my method create two, the first time stamp then the second 'coins' all in one header.

```
timestamp     dashcoin   litecoin   dogecoin    nxt
```

How can we separate like `pd.DataFrame(columns=coins)`

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your string to `list` with `[]` and then use `+` operator with your `coins`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=[['timestamp'] + coins])

In [148]: res
Out[148]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [timestamp, dashcoin, litecoin, dogecoin, nxt]
Index: []
```

Or with one list:

```
new_coins = ['timestamp'] + coins
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_coins)

In [152]: res
Out[152]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [timestamp, dashcoin, litecoin, dogecoin, nxt]
Index: []
```